# JAX-WS on Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-ws

I am trying to deploy a JAX-WS on a Tomcat server. I have looked around the web and followed instructions I found [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/223670/Web-Services/java/Deploy-JAXWS-Mustang-WS-Tomcat) and [here](http://puretech.paawak.com/2010/03/09/running-jax-ws-with-tomcat/) but to no avail. I get the following error and have no idea how to correct the issue.

```
SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamException java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamException
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3827)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4343)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:823)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:807)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostDeployer.addChild(StandardHostDeployer.java:903)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils.invokeMethod(MethodUtils.java:216)
at org.apache.commons.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:256)
at org.apache.commons.digester.Rule.end(Rule.java:276)
at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1058)
at org.apache.catalina.util.CatalinaDigester.endElement(CatalinaDigester.java:76)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1567)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostDeployer.install(StandardHostDeployer.java:488)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.install(StandardHost.java:863)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:483)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:983)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:349)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1091)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:789)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1083)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:480)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:2313)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:556)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:287)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:425)
```

- Error listenerStart
- Context startup failed due to previous errors
Jun 30, 2011 10:04:25 AM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextDestroyed
INFO: WSSERVLET13: JAX-WS context listener destroyed

here is my sun-jaxws.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  <endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml.ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime" version="2.0">
<endpoint name="ActionMutatorProxy" implementation="com.hyr.boa.transport.ActionMutatorProxy" url-pattern="/action_mutator_proxy" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `NoClassDefFoundError` thrown at deploy time means that a class definition that *was* present on the build path (e.g. the Java code compiles) cannot be found at runtime. The compile-time class path is not the same as the deploy-time class path with Tomcat (and other containers).

You need to put `jaxp-api.jar` into `WEB-INF/lib` or `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matt. I did what you recommended but to no avail. i also aded the latest javaee-api6.0.jar. I also noticed another peculiar error: `validateJarFile(C:\PRIMS\FIR\src\web2\WEB-INF\lib\j2ee.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class - validateJarFile(C:\PRIMS\FIR\src\web2\WEB-INF\lib\javaee-api-6.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class`

Comment: http://simplysimple.info/tomcat-error-jar-not-loaded-servlet-spec-23-section-972-offending-class-javaxservletservletclass/