# Jax-ws war deploys, but gives 404 on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jax-ws

First off I have looked at the suggested similar questions - because this is apparently a fairly common problem - and have not found an answer yet.Where did I go wrong? Downloaded latest JAXWS-RI and copied all the .jar files over manually. Then cobbled together a web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems,Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
           com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldTomcatService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldTomcatService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloWorldTomcatService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    </web-app>
```

and a sun-jaxws.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime" version="2.0">
    <endpoint name="HelloWorldTomcatService" implementation="com.myservice.ws.Hello" url-pattern="/HelloWorldTomcatService"/>
</endpoints>
```

and a couple java files

```
package com.myservice.ws;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService
public interface WebServiceInterface {
    @WebMethod
    String printMessage();
}

package com.myservice.ws;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.myservice.ws.WebServiceInterface")
public class Hello implements WebServiceInterface{
    @Override
    public String printMessage() {
        return "message";
    }
}
```

I placed the four files in the appropriate directory structure and build a war file in eclipse and copied it to the Tomcat webapps folder. The war was exploded and shows up on the manager console, but it does not start and all attempts to access it in a browser fail as well.

**Update:**

Here is an except from catalina log.

```
24-Jun-2016 11:22:42.164 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/HelloWorldTomcatService]
24-Jun-2016 11:22:42.171 INFO [localhost-startStop-6] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\HelloWorldTomcatService.war
24-Jun-2016 11:22:42.261 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-6] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
24-Jun-2016 11:22:42.262 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more components marked the context as not correctly configured
24-Jun-2016 11:22:42.262 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/HelloWorldTomcatService] startup failed due to previous errors
24-Jun-2016 11:22:42.265 INFO [localhost-startStop-6] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\HelloWorldTomcatService.war has finished in 94 ms
24-Jun-2016 12:53:45.577 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/HelloWorldTomcatService]
24-Jun-2016 12:53:45.596 INFO [localhost-startStop-7] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\HelloWorldTomcatService.war
24-Jun-2016 12:53:45.665 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-7] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
```

Even more logs:

```
22-Jun-2016 17:32:47.921 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\HelloWorldTomcatService.war
22-Jun-2016 17:32:48.036 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXmlParser.parseWebXml Parse error in application web.xml file at file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%208.5/webapps/HelloWorldTomcatService/WEB-INF/web.xml
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not resolve XML resource [null] with public ID [-//Sun Microsystems,Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN], system ID [http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_3.dtd] and base URI [file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%208.5/webapps/HelloWorldTomcatService/WEB-INF/web.xml] to a known, local entity.
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.LocalResolver.resolveEntity(LocalResolver.java:155)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.EntityResolver2Wrapper.resolveEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntityAsPerStax(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1461)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXmlParser.parseWebXml(WebXmlParser.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1110)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:298)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5076)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

22-Jun-2016 17:32:48.051 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan Failed to scan [file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%208.5/lib/hk2-core.jar] from classloader hierarchy
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\lib\hk2-core.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:326)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:276)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1887)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1122)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:298)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5076)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059153/cannot-run-jax-ws-java-web-service-on-apache-tomcat, but not the same. FIles are in the correct places.

Comment: What URL are you using to access the service?

Comment: @kolossus http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldTomcatService, http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldTomcatService/HellowWorldTomcatService, and a few others. Also tried changing the URL pattern to see if that helped. Homepage and manager work, btw.

Comment: Your logs indicate that the application didn't deploy successfully, hence the 404

Comment: @kolossus could you help determine why? AFAIK I'm doing everything correctly.

Comment: The log excerpt you've posted indicates that The error occurred earlier in the deployment. It'll be nigh impossible to tell without seeing earlier log output

Comment: ` java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\lib\hk2-core.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)`. There's the problem right there. Is that file in that location?

Comment: It is now. Still getting the xml error, though.

Comment: @kolossus So, the problem was that the header for the web.xml was obsolete. Replacing it did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case anyone was curious: the issue I was having was that the header for web.xml was incompatible with the version of Tomcat I was using - or deprecated, I don't know.

The header that's working now is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
      version="2.4">
...
```

There was also a warning that hk2-core.jar was missing. I'm not sure that would have been an issue if I'd fixed the xml problem first, but it was a good catch so, props to Kolossus.